# Best way to work with forms between mobile and desktop

Tags: android, ios, mysql, windows, excel

The situation: 
I would like to fill in a form/protocol on a tablet (probably Android, second choice iOS). When I am ready, I want to sent it to a server and watch and edit it on a desktop pc (Windows 7).

The question:
What would be the best solution to achieve this?

My thoughts so far:
 - export it as csv from tablet and import it in excel with a template (would be the best, because everyone knows excel, but it should be automated)
 - export it to a database (MySQL?) but how to access it from the pc? Another program or can excel handle that?
 - export it as pdf, but it wouldn't be edible?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me a lot in completing what I was trying to do, which is similar to yours. [Restful API for Android and IOS using Asp.net Web API 2](http://www.tutecentral.com/restful-api-android-ios-using-asp-net-web-api-2/)